# Choosing CPU architecture for LLVM/CLANG

Tags: hardware, cpu, llvm, clang

I am designing TTL serial computer, and I am struggling on choosing architecture more suitable for LLVM compiler backend (I want to be able to run any C++ software there). There will be no MMU, no multiplication/division, no hardware stack, no interrupts.

I have 2 main options:

1) 8-bit memory, 8-bit ALU, 8-bit registers (~12-16). Memory address width 24 bit. So I will need to use 3 registers as IP and 3 registers for any memory location.

Needless to say that any address calculations would be pure pain to implement in compiler.

2) 24-bit memory, 24-bit ALU, 24-bit registers (~6-8). Flat memory, nice. The drawbacks is that due to serial nature of the design, each operation would take 3 time more clocks, even if we are operating on some booleans. 24-bit memory data width is expensive. And it's harder to implement in hardware in general.

---

The question is : Do you think implementing all c++ features on this 8-bit, stack-less based hardware is possible, or I need to have more complex hardware to have generated code of reasonable quality & speed?

Comment: This may be a naive question, but why do you have to implement all of C++'s features? Can't you just use write a new LLVM target architecture, and Clang will compile C++ without problems?

Comment: @Dan Cecile That is exactly what I am going to do. But you can see that writing LLVM backend for 8-bit CPU with 24-bit memory space might be a little non-trivial.

Comment: So you have 4 parts; figuring out how to implement the [LLVM assembly language](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) works with your hardware, copying and adapting an [existing LLVM target](https://github.com/earl/llvm-mirror/tree/master/lib/Target) to work with your hardware, figuring out how to get Clang to [generate 8-bit LLVM bytecode](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TargetInfo.html) ([pointer sizes are configurable](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Re-targeting-clang-to-a-new-architecture-tp761920p762813.html)), then changing your hardware to be more suitable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I second the suggestion to use LCC.  I used it in this homebrew 16-bit RISC project: http://fpgacpu.org/xsoc/cc.html .

I don't think it should make much difference whether you build the 8-bit variant and use 3 add-with-carries to increment IP, or the 24-bit variant and do the whole thing in hardware.  You can hide the difference in your assembler.

If you look at my article above, or an even simpler CPU here: http://fpgacpu.org/papers/soc-gr0040-paper.pdf you will see you really don't need that many operators / instructions to cover the integer C repetoire.  In fact there is an lcc utility (ops) to print the min operator set for a given machine.

For more information see my article on porting lcc to a new machine here: http://www.fpgacpu.org/usenet/lcc.html

Once I had ported lcc, I wrote an assembler, and it synthesized a larger repetoire of instructions from the basic ones.  For example, my machine had load-byte-unsigned but not load-byte-signed, so I emitted this sequence:

```
lbs rd,imm(rs) ->
  lbu rd,imm(rs)
  lea r1,0x80
  xor rd,r1
  sub rd,r1
```

So I think you can get by with this min cover of operations:

```
  registers
  load register with constant
  load rd = *rs
  store *rs1 = rs2
  + - (w/ w/o carry)    // actually can to + with - and ^
  >> 1                  // << 1 is just +
  & ^                   // (synthesize ~ from ^, | from & and ^)
  jump-and-link rd,rs   // rd = pc, pc = rs
  skip-z/nz/n/nn rs     // skip next insn on rs==0, !=0, <0, >=0
```

Even simpler is to have no registers (or equivalently blur registers with memory -- all registers have a memory address).

Set aside a register for SP, and write the function prolog/epilog handler in the compiler and you won't have to worry about stack instructions.  There's just code to store each of the callee save registers, adjust the SP by the frame size, and so forth.

Interrupts (and return from interrupts) are straightforward.  All you need to do is force a jump-and-link instruction into the instruction register.  If you chose the bit pattern for that to be something like 0, and put the right addresses into the source register rs (especially if it is r0), it can be done with a flip-flop reset input or an extra force-to-0 and gate.  I use a similar trick in the second paper above.

Interesting project.  I see a TTL / 7400 contest is underway and I was thinking myself of how simple a machine could you get away with and would it be cheating to add a 32 KB or 128 KB async SRAM to the machine to hold the code and data.

Anyway, happy hacking!

p.s.

1) You will want to decide how large each integral type is.  You can certainly make char, short, int, long, long long, etc. the same size, one 24b word, if you wish, although it won't be compliant in min representation ranges.

2) And although I focused on lcc here, you were asking about C++.  I recommend persuing C first.  Once you have things figured out for C, including *, /, % operators in software, etc., it should be more tractable to move to full blown C++ whether in LLVM or GCC. The difference between C and C++ is "only" the extra vtables and RTTI tables and code sequences (entirely built up out the primitive C integer operator repetoire) required to handle virtual function calls, pointer to member dereference, dynamic casts, static constructors, exception handling, etc.

Comment: p.s. I was thinking. You should build the 24b variant in preference to the 8b variant.  It is not because wider data operations require multiple instructions each, rather because you really need a concept of a linear 24b address space for instructions and data.  While you can synthesize a 24b load out of 3 8b loads, you need a 24b address (and a 24b address increment) to handle instructin fetch, program counter, and PC increment in hardware.  It is not clear how you could handle programs larger than 256 instructions if you only have 8b addresses.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, It is possible for c compiler. i am not sure for c++, though.

LLVM/CLang could be hard choice for 8bit computer,

Instead, first try [lcc](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/retargeting_lcc.htm), then second llvm/etc, HTH.

Bill Buzbee succeed to retarget lcc compiler for his **Magic-1**(known as **[homebrewcpu](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/)**).

Although the hardware design and construction of Magic-1 usually gets the most attention, the largest part of the project (by far) has been developing/porting the software.   To this end, I've had to write an assembler and linker from scratch, retarget a C compiler, write and port the standard C libraries, write a simplified operating system and then port a more sophisticated one.   It's been a challenge, but a fun one.  I suppose I'm somewhat twisted, but I happen to enjoy debugging difficult problems.  And, when the bug you're trying to track down could involve one or more of: hardware design flaw, loose or broken wire, loose or bad TTL chip, assembler bug, linker bug, compiler bug, C runtime library bug, or finally a bug in the program in question there's lot of opportunity for fun.    Oh, and I also don't have the luxury of blaming the bugs on anyone else.

I'm continually amazed that the damn thing runs at all, much less runs as well as it does.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, stackless hardware is already poorly suited for C and C++ code. If you have nested function calls, you will need to emulate a stack in software anyway, which of course is much slower.

When going the stackless route, you will probably allocate most of your variables as 'static', and have no re-entrant functions. In this case, 6502-style addressing modes can be effective. You could for example have these addressing modes:

1. Immediate address (24bit) as part of opcode
2. Immediate address (24bit) plus index register (8bit)
3. Indirect access: immediate 24bit address to memory, which contains the actual address
4. Indirect access: 24 bit address to memory, 8 bit index register added to value from memory.

The address modes outlined above would allow efficient access to arrays, structures and objects allocated at a constant address (static allocation). They would be less efficient (but still usable) for dynamically and stack-allocated objects.

You would also get some benefit from your serial design: usually the 24 bit + 8 bit addition does not take 24 cycles, but you can instead short-circuit the addition when carry is 0.

Instead of mapping the IP as registers directly, you could allow changing it only through goto/branch instructions, using the same address modes as above. Jumps into dynamically computed addresses are quite rare so it makes more sense to give the whole 24-bit address directly in the opcode.

I think that if you design the CPU carefully, you can use many C++ features quite efficiently. However, do not expect that any random C++ code would run fast on such a limited CPU.

Comment: Yeah, stackless code is just useless : I still want to be able to crosscompile existing code for it. So I will have to use emulated stack.

Comment: You could implement a hardware stack; it requires just two more instructions and increment/decrement is quite fast and easy in a serial architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is certainly possible, but I doubt it will be usable (at lest for C++ code). As it was already noted, first problem is lack of stack. Next, bunch of C++ relies heavily on dynamic memory allocation, also C++ "internal" structures are quite big.

So, as it seems to me, it will be better, if you:

1. Get rid of C++ requirement (or at least, limit yourself to some subset)
2. Use 24 bits, not 8 bits for everything (for registers as well)
3. Add hardware stack

Comment: Well, implementing subset is harder than whole C++. In the latter case I only need to write clang/llvm backend. Why absence of hardware stack such a critical problem? Isn't software one allows to do the same?

Comment: If you don't care about any performance - then you're fine, yes :)

Answer (score -1):

You are not going to be able to run "any" C++ code there.  For example fork(), system(), etc.  Anything that clearly relies on interrupts for example.  You can get a long way there, sure.
Now do you mean any programs that can/have been written in C++ or are you limiting yourself to the language only and not the libraries that are commonly associated with C/C++?  The language itself is a much easier rule to live with.

I think the easier question/answer, is, why not just try?  What have you tried so far?  It could be argued that the x86 is an 8-bit machine, no regard for alignment and many 8 bit instructions.  the msp430 was ported to llvm to show how easily and quickly it could be done,  I would like to see that platform with better support (not where my strengths lie otherwise I would be doing it) a 16 bit platform.  no mmu. does have a stack and interrupts sure, dont have to use them and if you remove library rules then what is left that needs an interrupt?

I would look at llvm but note that the documentation produced that shows how easy it is to port, is dated and wrong and you basically have to figure it out on your own from the compiler sources.  llc has a book, known for that, not optimized.  Sources dont compile well on modern computers, always having to go backwards in time to use it, any time I go near it after an evening just trying to build it as is I give up.  vbcc, simple, clean, documented, not unfriendly to smaller processors.  Is it C++, dont remember.  Of all of them the easiest to get a compiler up and running though.  Of all of them LLVM is the most attractive and most useful when all said and done.  dont go near gcc or even think of it, duct tape and bailing wire inside holding it together.

Have you invented your instruction set yet?  do you have a simulator and assembler yet?  Look up lsasim at github to find my instruction set.  You can write an llvm backend for mine as practice for yours...grin...(my vbcc backend is horrible, I need to start over)...

You have to have some idea of how the high level will be implemented but you really have to start with an instruction set and an instruction set simulator and an assembler of some sort.  Then start hand converting C/C++ code into assembly for your instruction set, that should pretty quickly get you through "can I do this without a stack", etc.  In this process define your calling convention, implement more C/C++ code by hand using your calling convention. THEN dig into a compiler and make a back end.  I think you should consider vbcc as a stepping stone, then head for LLVM if it appears like it (the isa) will work.